# Issue with astype losing decimals

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point

I have a problem with an `astype`, when I do it I'm losing decimals that are really important cause it's for longitude and latitude coordinates.

```
df[["Latitud","Longitud"]] = df[["Latitud","Longitud"]].astype(float)
```

Here is what I need:

```
df[["Latitud", "Longitud"]]
```

Latitud Longitud

```
0   -34.807023  -56.0336021
1   -34.8879924 -56.1846677
2   -34.8895332 -56.1560728
3   -34.8860972 -56.1635684
4   -34.7242753 -56.2012194
393 -34.8575722 -56.0534571
394 -34.7448815 -56.2132383
395 -34.8539222 -56.2320066
396 -34.8513169 -56.1721213
397 -34.8220428 -55.9906951
```

And here it's what `astype` gives me:

```
df[["Latitud", "Longitud"]]
```

Latitud Longitud

```
0   -35 -56
1   -35 -56
2   -35 -56
3   -35 -56
4   -35 -56
393 -35 -56
394 -35 -56
395 -35 -56
396 -35 -56
397 -35 -56
```

I try with no luck:

```
df[["Latitud","Longitud"]] = pd.to_numeric(df[["Latitud","Longitud"]],errors='coerce')

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.08f}'.format
```

How can I can keep my decimals?

Comment: Please create a [mre] and [edit] your question to include it. Show code and results as text, not as images.

Comment: Can you explain why you hoped that `{:.0f}` would preserve decimals? It literally means "round to 0 decimals".

Comment: I tried with an {:.08f} with no luck and then I delete the 8. Sorry for that, but still no luck!

Comment: From what data type are you converting to float? The logic looks right, though. After using `astype(float)`, did you try to check the actual value in an example cell, e.g., `df["Latitud"].iloc[0]`? I had instances myself where a printed dataframe did not reflect the actual type, like in your case. Just to be sure, you should also update pandas.

Comment: Oh, I try it, and give me the full value, but how can I make it to do in the table? I use google colab, can I update pandas there?

Comment: If I understand correctly, `df["Latitud"].iloc[0]` gives you the expected floating value, not an integer, correct? If so, then you may have accidentally changed the settings of the float format. In that case, nothing is wrong with your data, just with the way it is printed. To fix it, restart your Python kernel (if applicable), change `pd.options.display.float_format`, and/or update pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Well the thing that solve the problem was using:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.8f}'.format
```

Only to discover that was not the problem! But hope can help someone with decimals!